# Unrecognized import path

Tags: go

Just installed go via homebrew, trying to install a package and getting the following:

```
~: go get https://github.com/vova616/chipmunk
package https:/github.com/vova616/chipmunk: unrecognized import path "https:/github.com/vova616/chipmunk"
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
go get github.com/vova616/chipmunk
```

You need to remove the `https://`.

For more information, run `go help remote`.